# Unable to view my profile

Tags: bug, android-app

It shows failed to load profile content.
I can view other user's profile but it stuck when I try to view my own profile.

[image]

- App Version: 1.0.94
- Device Manufacturer: LENOVO
- Device Model: Lenovo K33a42

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (K33_S156_170220_ROW)

Comment: Try to close and then reopen the app

Comment: I tried even reinstalling​ the app, updated app but still same

Comment: Seems you're trying to see your [Magento.SE] profile? Currently, I see [2 Magento accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poAkx.png) which looks like an artifact of merging the account (or bug/cache). Wait for a while until it's resolved in the server, then try again.

Comment: @Disney Yes I was trying to see my Magento profile. Yes there are two accounts from a long time (more than 2 years, it is there on website as well). How this can be resolved?

Comment: I recommend to post a new question regarding that Magento profiles as a [bug] (and probably [support]), and wait for SE officials to help you.

Comment: Thank you @Disney I have posted a new question as you recommended.